# How do I get the numbers and alphabets from a string?

Tags: java

I'm trying to work out a way of splitting up a string in java that follows a pattern like so:

```
String a = "24ab4h";
```

The results from this should be the following:

```
st[0] = "24";
st[1] = "a";
st[2] = "b";
st[3] = "4";
st[4] = "h";
```

However, I'm completely stumped as to how I can achieve this. Please, can someone help me out? I have tried searching online for a similar problem, however, it's very difficult to phrase it correctly in a search.

Comment: What is the rule for splitting?  Break after every letter or 4?

Comment: splitting number and alphabet.

Comment: But you split "ab" in "a" and "b", but you did not split "24" so ? ^^

Comment: Split every character and then concatinate two or more consecutive characters if they are numbers.

Comment: I don't want to split numbers but I wanna split alphabet.

Comment: I have used this code to split But it is not splitting "ab" as "a" and "b" 
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  String str =sc.nextLine();
  String strA[]=str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

Answer (score 2):

If you use a `split()` function you'll loose the elements which are used as delimiters so I think use a Pattern is better :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+|[a-zA-Z]").matcher("24ab4h");

    List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    while (m.find()) {
        res.add(m.group());
    }     
}
```

The pattern will detect all group of digits OR alpabet char alone, then it will add all into a `List` (better than `array` because you don't know the size)

---

If you really want an array at the end, 2 solutions for `List<String> ->String[]` :

- `String[] array = res.toArray(new String[res.size()]);`
- `String[] array = res.stream().toArray(String[]::new);`

Answer (score 0):

Try to process your String in a loop, char by char.

```
String a = "24ab4h";
```

If focused char (`2`) is number - check next char (`4`). If next char is also a number - continue scanning. If next char differs from number - save focused char (or focused char sequence, in this example it is - `24`).

The same logic for alphabet chars.

Comment: I have used this code to split But it is not splitting "ab" as "a" and "b"  
                Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  String str =sc.nextLine();
  String strA[]=str.split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

Comment: Yes. I understand what you want, but I can't help you with correct regex expression for split method. Alternatively you can use `StringBuilder` for numbers. And alphabetic chars process without StringBuilder (because you need only 1 char). When part of the string is ready, add it to ArrayList. When you completed processing whole string, convert ArrayList to simple array of strings. `String[] st = arrayList.toArray(new String[0]);` So you will get 
`st[0] = "24";
st[1] = "a";
st[2] = "b";
st[3] = "4";
st[4] = "h";`

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    /*
     * Stack stack = new Stack(5); stack.push("10"); stack.push("20");
     * stack.push("20"); stack.push("20"); stack.push("20");
     * stack.push("20"); stack.push("20"); stack.displayStack();
     */

    String a = "24ab4h";
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(splitString(a)));

}

private static String[] splitString(String a) {

    char[] result = new char[a.length()];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (isNumber(a.charAt(i))) {
            if (i != 0 && !isNumber(a.charAt(i - 1)))
                sb.append(" ");
                sb.append(a.charAt(i));
        } else {
            sb.append(" ");
            sb.append(a.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString().split(" ");
}

private static boolean isNumber(char c) {
    try {
        Integer i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(c));
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```